# R ggrepel: hiding some labels

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggrepel

Hi I been getting Aesthetics error when trying to only display labels for certain subsets. For example.

```
library("ggplot2")
library(gplots)
library(ggrepel)

set.seed(10)
data <- data.frame(label=letters[1:21], number= runif(21, min=0, max=100))
data$label <-factor(data$label)

ggplot(data, aes(x=label, y=number, fill=data$label )) +
geom_bar(stat="identity") +
geom_text_repel(data=  data[data$number > 80,], aes(label =data$label ), 
                  arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.01, 'npc')), box.padding = unit(1.5, 'lines'),color="black"   )
```

When I do this I get the following error

```
Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (2): label, x, y, fill
```

even if I replace the label with a vector such as `c("label1","label2")`
I still get an error.

I'm doing something wrong but I can't figure it out.  The only way I can do this is to create a separate vector with the same length and use that as the label, however I think there is a way to subset directly. thanks!

Comment: Never use `$` insed `aes`.

Answer (score 3):

Change the code to:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=label, y=number, fill=data$label )) +
geom_bar(stat="identity") +
geom_text_repel(data=  data[data$number > 80,], aes(label =label ), ##<- Change here
                  arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.01, 'npc')), box.padding = unit(1.5, 'lines'),color="black"   )
```

The problem is that in the call to `aes` within `geom_text_repel()` you use `data$label`, a column within the 21 row dataframe, whereas you want `label` to be evaluated within the 2 row subset of the data.

In this case, you've obscured the problem by calling your data `data`, it might be more straightforward to spot the error if you'd called it something more meaningful.

Comment: great thanks, it still failed, but your comment help since I notice that the fill was also incorrect with data$label.  It worked as soon as changed it to label. 

`ggplot(data, aes(x=label, y=number, fill=label )) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  geom_text_repel(data=  data[data$number > 80,], aes(label =label ), ##<- Change here
                  arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.01, 'npc')), box.padding = unit(1.5, 'lines'),color="black"   )`

thanks again; much appreciate it, A